# Service Bus Topic Subscription filter searching a value in array

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I've been searching about how to create a SQL filter for a topic subscription in Azure Service Bus searching a value in an array, but I didn't find anything and I don't know if it's possible?

I have a message like:

```json
{
  "myArray":[ "value1", "value2", "value3" ],
  ...
}
```

If the array contains the value "value2", I want to send the message to appear for "subscription2", but I don't know how to create the filter.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```sql
'value2' in (myArray)
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot apply a filter on the content/ body. Filters only work on the headers. You'd have to be creative by bringing the values into the header and use `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Thank  you! I was confused. I didn't notice that another method was adding properties to the header with some content from the message. The property name was the same, I thought it was applying the filter to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Sean Feldman` for the comment.

**Code to filter an array**.

```
 string[] SBFilter = { "Topic1", "Topic2", "Topic3", "Topic4" };
       if (SBFilter.Contains("Topic3"))
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Topic Present");
        }
        else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Topic Not Present");
         }
```

**SQL Commmand** to filter a table for a specific string from a column

```
select * from TABLE_Name where COLUMN_Name[1] like '%1%'
```

**Code to search the Service Bus Topic Subscription**.

```
 public class Program
        {
            static ServiceBusAdministrationClient adminClient;

            static readonly string connectionString = "ConnectionString";

            static readonly string topicName = "TopicName";

            static readonly string subscriptionAllOrders = "AllOrders";
            static readonly string subscriptionColorBlueSize10Orders = "ColorBlueSize10Orders";
            static readonly string subscriptionColorRed = "ColorRed";
            static readonly string subscriptionHighPriorityRedOrders = "HighPriorityRedOrders";

            public static async Task Main()
            {
                try
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Creating the Service Bus Administration Client object");
                    adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Creating the topic {topicName}");
                    await adminClient.CreateTopicAsync(topicName);

                    Console.WriteLine($"Creating the subscription {subscriptionAllOrders} for the topic with a True filter ");
                    await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(
                            new CreateSubscriptionOptions(topicName, subscriptionAllOrders),
                            new CreateRuleOptions("AllOrders", new TrueRuleFilter()));


                    Console.WriteLine($"Creating the subscription {subscriptionColorBlueSize10Orders} with a SQL filter");
                    await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(
                            new CreateSubscriptionOptions(topicName, subscriptionColorBlueSize10Orders),
                            new CreateRuleOptions("BlueSize10Orders", new SqlRuleFilter("color='blue' AND quantity=10")));

                    Console.WriteLine($"Creating the subscription {subscriptionColorRed} with a SQL filter");
                    await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(topicName, subscriptionColorRed);
                    await adminClient.DeleteRuleAsync(topicName, subscriptionColorRed, "$Default");
                    await adminClient.CreateRuleAsync(topicName, subscriptionColorRed, new CreateRuleOptions
                    {
                        Name = "RedOrdersWithAction",
                        Filter = new SqlRuleFilter("user.color='red'"),
                        Action = new SqlRuleAction("SET quantity = quantity / 2; REMOVE priority;SET sys.CorrelationId = 'low';")

                    }
                    );

                    Console.WriteLine($"Creating the subscription {subscriptionHighPriorityRedOrders} with a correlation filter");
                    await adminClient.CreateSubscriptionAsync(
                            new CreateSubscriptionOptions(topicName, subscriptionHighPriorityRedOrders),
                            new CreateRuleOptions("HighPriorityRedOrders", new CorrelationRuleFilter() { Subject = "red", CorrelationId = "high" }));

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Output after filtering the Service bus topic using code.
[image]

Service Bus Topic

[image]

SQL Filter in Service Bus Subscription

[image]

Reference taken from [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-filter-examples)